# PHP Sorting by date?

Tags: php, sorting

I'm making a news feed which stores dates as a string like `Tuesday 05 June 2012 04:14:44 PM`.

I want to do two things.

1. Sort the news feed by date (newest to oldest)
2. If the date is today's date, show only the time(which is also sorted).

Comment: `which stores dates as a string` what on earth makes people to do so? no, i'm realy interested, cause i can find no reason.

Comment: I had it sorted by date, but I couldn't figure out how to sort the time as well, at least not without a lot of embedded if and while statements etc.

Comment: You can store the news by id, or use strtotime(), you'll get numbers, the higher the numbers, the recent it is, you can also then convert it to string with the date() function, google is your friend :)

Answer (score 3):

I would change the storage to store some "[unix timestamp](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php)". From that you can print out [whatever format of date you like](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). And also, it's a number and is very easily sortable.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this will work for your problem, yet i advise you to modify your table design if possible.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM newsfeed");

$records = array();
$i = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $records[$i] = array('news_idPK' => $row['news_idPK'],
                     'date' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($row['date'])),
                     'news' => $row['news']
    );
    $i++;
}
usort($records, "cmp");

function cmp($a, $b) {
    $a = strtotime($a['date']);
    $b = strtotime($b['date']);
    return $a - $b;
}

$ctr = count($records)-1;
for($x=$ctr; $x>=0; $x--)
{
    $newsDate = date("l d F Y h:i:s A", strtotime($records[$x]['date']));
    if(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($records[$x]['date'])) == date("Y-m-d"))
    {
        $newsDate = date("h:i:s A",strtotime($records[$x]['date']));
    }
    echo $records[$x]['news_idPK']." - ".$newsDate." - ".$records[$x]['news']." <br/>";
}
```

Comment: As they say [it is **strongly** recommended that you use the **mysqli** extension instead](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.overview.php)

Comment: .:oh yeah, sorry bout that.tnx! :)

Answer (score -2):

This sorting method isn't effective. You can add an ID column and sort by ID. each time someone post a post , and it's inserted to the feed -  a incremented ID will be inserted. it's parallel to date sorting - you want the newest.

it's the most recommended and effective sorting method.

Comment: I thought of that before, but I thought something wouldn't work with it. Thanks :)

Comment: hm... but why? i thought that storing date in special datetime field will solve all the problems. with ID - how can you select all for e.g. 'yesterdays' posts?